# method not defined when calling from inside an event listener

Tags: javascript

I have a Game class with canvas and I add an event listener for mouse clicks in the constructor.

I have a method that should log the position of the mouse click, but I get error that this method is not defined:

```
class Game {

    constructor(canvas, event) {
        this.canvas = canvas;                        
        this.canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
            getClickPosition(canvas, e)
        })
    }

    getClickPosition(canvas, e) {
        const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect()
        const x = event.clientX - rect.left
        const y = event.clientY - rect.top
        console.log("x: " + x + " y: " + y)
    }
    }
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
const game = new Game(canvas)
```

Comment: Classic question. Use `e => { ... }` not `function(e) { ... }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an [arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (to preserve `this`) and call `this.getClickPosition()`:

```
this.canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  this.getClickPosition(canvas, e);
});
```

Comment: Andy, thank you! I also saw your comment and I edited my post and fixed a few things I left by mistake. Your code works! I'm new to JS, why did the arrow function preserve `this`?

Comment: Arrow functions don't have their own `this` (or `arguments`) so it borrows the context from the outer lexical environment. Before they came along you had to assign `this` to another variable like `self` and use `self` in the function instead. Arrow functions make life a lot easier.

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated